# Why is process.env.WHATEVER !== undefined if I set to undefined after it is set?

Tags: javascript

I have the following test script....

```
> process.env.SOMETHING === undefined
true
> process.env.SOMETHING = "asdsad";
'asdsad'
> process.env.SOMETHING === undefined
false
> process.env.SOMETHING = undefined
undefined
> process.env.SOMETHING === undefined
false
> process.env.SOMETHING == null
false
> !process.env.SOMETHING
false
> process.env.SOMETHING === "undefined"
true
```

Why does it get converted to a string?

Comment: This seems like something for which you'd simply check the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [that's what Node requires.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html#processenv), at least for now.

> Assigning a property on `process.env` will implicitly convert the value to a string. **This behavior is deprecated.** Future versions of Node.js may throw an error when the value is not a string, number, or boolean.

Comment: Might be good to add that as of Node 17 there's a warning: "This behavior is deprecated. Future versions of Node.js may throw an error when the value is not a string, number, or boolean."

Comment: Interesting I don't see the warning but I am using 18 (https://gist.github.com/purejgleason/618e76d3ab49efe871aadbac901125f5)

Comment: @Jackie It says that *future* (not current) versions *may* have the behavior change so that it throws - and it's said in the docs, not when you try to assign to the property.